# Getting an exception when .exe tested on another system

Tags: wpf, exception, assemblies

I am working on the WPF  application and i have created an exe file.
When i run the exe file on my computer,it works perfectly.But when i try using my exe with another system.It throws an exception and when i debug the exception it says...

> Cannot find type
>   'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid'.
>   The assembly used when compiling might
>   be different than that used when
>   loading and the type is missing. 
>   Error at object 'MyWork.App' in
>   markup file 'MyWork.App;component/app.xaml' Line 15
>   Position 6.

Any idea ?

Regards,

Sangram Nandkhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't installed the dll that contains `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`. This is part of the WPF Toolkit so you will need to either install that on the target machine or include the dll in your installation program.

If you don't want to create an installer then you can merge assemblies using [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en) which:

> is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly. It works on executables and DLLs alike and comes with several options for controlling the processing and format of the output.

Comment: Do u mean i need to add reference of wpf toolkit DLL in my references,?? i tried this but did not change any thing i am still getting same message..

Comment: @Sangram - I mean you have to actually copy the dll onto the target machine. This can be by either installing the WPF Toolkit (not ideal) or including the dll in your application installer.

Comment: No....I right clicked on the references(present in my project) then and selected ADD REFERENCE and then added WPF TOOLKIT DLL by browse mode from another project...is it right ??

Comment: Actually i dont want to create installer ,i just want to create an .exe file which will be executing on different system..is it possible ?? or i will have to create an installer ??

Comment: @  Chris: now i am getting ur point ..u mean DLL used (wpf toolkit) on my system is not present on  the another system ..so i some how need to install that DLL (either using installer or using ILMerge )..Am i right ??

Comment: @ Chris: i understood the concept,thanx for the Help..if u can post any link explaining how to use  ILMerge..i will be very thankful .cyaa

Comment: @Sangram - I'd have to search to find out. Also there should be a link from the download page.

Comment: @Chris: I have created an installer and its working fine..post tutorial link for ILMerge if possible....